Error message while trying to install core lightning
I'm trying to run core lightning by following the installation guide provided at corelightning.org. I have taken the binaries option. When I enter sudo tar -xvf <release>.tar.xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=2 and try to launch clighting by entering lightningd I get the following error message:

I have googled this library and nothing much comes up. What do I need to do about this error message?

You are missing the postgresql client libraries. If you are on Ubuntu you should be able to install the library using this:
sudo apt-get install libpq5

Then try running lightningd again.
